# MySqlDump - Empty dump by using Windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows

Tried out the mysqldump exe to get a local dump. Worked fine on MAC_OS. Just at windows i get a exit-code 1 and a local empty .sql file.

I used following code:

```
$command = ''.$locationDumpExe.' --user='.$dbuser.' --password='.$dbpassword.' --no-data --host=localhost  '.$dbname.' > '.$dumpfile.'';

exec($command,$output,$return_var);
```

**The variables had been set like the following:**

- $locationDumpExe = "/xampp/mysql/bin";
- $dbuser = "root";
- $dbpassword = "";
- $dbname = "test_db";
- $dumpfile = "testdump.sql"

**The return_var returns 1**

The test_db has an amount of 90 - 100 tables and is filled with ~ 50 - 100 datasets. Maybe this is the issue?

As I said on Mac_OS the dump works fine but for good reasons I also have to use the dump functionality on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Echo out the command and try it on the command line yourself.

Comment: Same result, thx for try.

Comment: If you remove the piping `> testdump.sql` from the command when you paste it to the command line, does it give you any messages?

Comment: Thanks for your help but giving the absolute path worked fine for me. Maybe I also made some issue by echo the command :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you try with windows you have to specify the full path of mysqldump.exe

```
C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe -h {hostname} -u {usernamne} -p{password} {dbName} > path/to/store/sql/file.
```

Hope this helps. 
Thanks
Suman W.

Comment: Finally I got the result to this issue. Your solution has been true. :) Changed my $locationDumpExe = 'c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe. Works fine now.

Comment: For further informations: After the right path i got the exit code: 2 -> This mainly turns up if you do not have the right permissions -> So i had to look wich username and password have the right permissions. - Just as further informations if someone also reads over this :)